# Angular - add json into array that's already got json in

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, jsonp

I'm getting jsonp and putting into an array. When i get near the bottom of the page i'm loading more jsonp and want to add that to the existing array. But instead of adding, its replacing what's already there.

```
function AppCtrl($scope, Portfolio, $log, $timeout, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
    $scope.posts = [];
    Portfolio.getPosts($scope);
    $scope.refresh = function() {

        console.log('Refreshing!');
        $timeout( function() {

        Portfolio.getPosts($scope);

        console.log('Refreshed!');

        //stop the ion-refresher from spinning
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');

        }, 1000);

    };

//get jsonp
function Portfolio($http, $log) {
    this.getPosts = function($scope) {
        $http.jsonp("http://test.uxco.co/json-test.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
            .success(function(result) {
                $scope.posts = result;  
                $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
            });
    };
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Update:

```
$scope.posts.push(result);
```

Seems to work but now the content isn't showing.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="p in posts">
      <div class="img-container">
          <img ng-src="{{ p.thumbnail }}">
      </div>
      <div class="title-container">
          <h2>{{ p.id }}</h2>                   
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use push to existing array

Comment: Instead `$scope.posts = result` do `$scope.posts.push(result)`

Answer (score 0):

```
function Portfolio($http, $log) {


    this.getPosts = function($scope) {
        $http.jsonp("http://test.uxco.co/json-test.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
            .success(function(result) {
                $scope.posts.push(result);  
                $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
            });
    };
}
```

Comment: I think that's working, but now nothing is being shown in the ng-repeat:

<div data-ng-repeat="p in posts">
                            <div class="img-container">
                               <img ng-src="{{ p.thumbnail }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="title-container">
                                <h2>{{ p.id }}</h2>                   
                            </div>
                        </div>

Comment: @user3930160  .success(function(result) { console.log(result) can you please add console.log like in example and add to your question what you get printed ?

Comment: I got it working using `$scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(result)`

Thanks for your help